# How to add skew to StepModel

Tags: python, skew, lmfit

I have a model made up of a sum of several lmfit StepModel(form='erf') steps, which gives a pretty good fit to my data. However, the residual shows some skew at each step. I can use `skew(output.result.residual)` to give me the skew over the entire dataset, but what I would really like is to have a value of skew for each component of the model, that is, a skew1 associated with step1, skew2 with step2, etc.

I've changed the code in examples/doc_builtinmodels_stepmodel.py to give an example of what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit.models import LinearModel, StepModel

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 201)
a = np.ones_like(x)
b = np.ones_like(x)

a[:48] = 0.0
a[48:77] = np.arange(77-48)/(77.0-48)
b[:10] = 0.0
b[10:39] = np.arange(39-10)/(39.0-10)

np.random.seed(0)
a = 110.2 * (a + 9e-3*np.random.randn(x.size)) + 12.0 + 2.22*x
b = 110.2 * (b + 9e-3*np.random.randn(x.size)) + 12.0 + 2.22*x

y = a + b

step_mod = StepModel(form='erf', prefix='s1_')
step2_mod = StepModel(form='erf', prefix='s2_')
line_mod = LinearModel(prefix='line_')

pars = line_mod.make_params(intercept=y.min(), slope=0)
pars += step_mod.guess(y, x=x, center=2.5)
pars += step2_mod.guess(y, x=x, center=2.5)

mod = step_mod + step2_mod + line_mod
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

out.plot(data_kws={'markersize':  1})
print(skew(out.result.residual))
```

I suspect I may have to build the skew directly into the StepModel() function, but I admit I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after - skewness of the fit residual?  I also don't follow what do you want `skew1` and `skew2` to do.   You have two step functions with linear ramps and an additional linear term.  Where does the skewness come in?

Comment: Running the example code above returns a residual with two sawtooth waves. If I run skew(out.result.residual) on the model, I get the skew for the entire range of data. Instead, I would like the skew for each sawtooth individually, so I can see if a certain sawtooth is left-skew or right-skew.

Comment: Well, you can extract the curves for the three components of the model (see `ModelResult.eval_components()`).  Maybe subtract each of those from the data? I'm not sure what you would do if the components overlap significantly, but maybe it will help...  I still don't understand what you would want a `skew` parameter to do.